# How to limit the amount of method for a delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have a `delegate`,and i want it only can be register for 5 times.
I know i can set the `delegate` `private` and write a `AddRegister()` method to control the amount of `registered` method.
Have any other ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetInvocationList` method on the delegate object and then call `Count` method on it. Something to the effect of the following

```
Mydel d1 = this.MyMethod;
int count = d1.GetInvocationList().Count();//Here count will be 1
```

Also I would prefer to have the registration combined with the above functionality in one place similar to the one you mentioned in your question. In this way you need not have to write the `count <= 5` condition wherever it is being registered. Hence it will be easier to maintain.

Hope this helps.